# Convert 8 bytes uint8_t array to 4 bytes array

Tags: arrays, arduino, hex

I am using Arduino and I want to save the XBee MAC (upper and lower bytes) in an uint8_t array.

Now I am reading bytes without problem but I am saving them in an uint8_t* array using 8 bytes.
I want to save them in a 4 bytes array.

For example, upper bytes are: 0013A200. No it uses: {0,0,1,3,A,2,0,0}, something like that.

I want to save them this way: {0x00, 0x13, 0xA2, 0x00}

Is it possible? I haven't found a way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is the following:

```
union {
  uint32_t dword;
  struct
  {
     uint8_t b0 : 4;
     uint8_t b1 : 4;
     uint8_t b2 : 4;
     uint8_t b3 : 4;
     uint8_t b4 : 4;
     uint8_t b5 : 4;
     uint8_t b6 : 4;
     uint8_t b7 : 4;
  } b;
//  uint8_t nibble[] : 4; // can't make an array!
} XbeeMAC;
```

...

```
XbeeMAC.b.b0 = 0;
XbeeMAC.b.b1 = 1;
XbeeMAC.b.b2 = 2;
XbeeMAC.b.b3 = 3;
XbeeMAC.b.b4 = 4;
XbeeMAC.b.b5 = 5;
XbeeMAC.b.b6 = 6;
XbeeMAC.b.b7 = 7;
Serial.print(F(" XbeeMAC.dword=")); 
Serial.println(XbeeMAC.dword,HEX);
```

outputs

```
 XbeeMAC.dword=76543210
```

Where you can not make an array of the nibbles, they get typed as and stored as individual uint8_t.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this:

```
uint8_t XbeeMAC[] = {0x00, 0x13, 0xA2, 0x00};
```